How can I thoroughly test a circuit that requires debouncing of several components?
I recently asked for help on a circuit using a D flip flop that lets me turn a relay on and off with a momentary push button switch. That circuit uses both a momentary push button switch and a relay with a coil to control a switch. Here's an updated schematic of the circuit based on the answers the question received:

If I don't have a well equipped test bench, and I'm new to circuit design and construction, how can I test this circuit to make sure it's working properly? It looks to me like I need to test several issues, in this order, since I have to be sure one item is working before I can reliably move on to test the next item:

Test that SW1 is being debounced properly.
Test that the RC circuit to hold pin 4, the RESET pin on the FF, is working properly so, on power-up, that line is pulled high and kept high until things "settle."
Test that the switch on the relay is debounced.

The most sophisticated piece of equipment I have is a low end oscilloscope:

(I know Amazon listings can vanish after time, so I included the photo, but the listing of the item, with details, is at available here.)
I would think I test the debouncing with the scope. Attach one lead to the output of the switch (after the pull down resistor and the RC circuit and the other scope lead to the ground. I'd do the same for the output of the switch. I need to make sure the scope is set to a frequency that will let me see the debouncing action. The problem I see is that the debouncing will be faster than my eye can see, so I don't know if that's the right way to test it or not. I'm not sure how to test the circuit for keeping the RESET pin high at startup, other than to be sure the FF always comes out in the state I want it to.
I'll be building this on a breadboard to make sure it works. I realize that things like how an FF will be set after power up can depend on a lot of small things, so it might come out as initially off in the breadboard setup, but then work differently once I etch a circuit board and solder everything in place.
How can a neophyte, without a lot of test equipment, check to be sure the switches are being debounced as I expect and that the RESET pin is always set to high on startup, and that the debouncing and reset line will work on the breadboard and on the final etched circuit board?

You could buy a cheapo logic analyzer from Amazon. They cost around 15€, depending where you’re from. You can then hook up the logic analyser to the push button and track the voltage level over time. You can use the saleae Logic software to track the signals. I don’t think you need more than that. The input voltag e is 3.3V which is easily supported by the logic analyzer. If you see bouncing, then the logic anywhere will show you fast translations from high to low.

Button switches may bounce more or less than 1ms, so your scope can easily trigger that. But use a standard cap with high ESR where tau> 100 us to limit the current unless you intend to arc.

"The problem I see is that the debouncing will be faster than my eye can see" Hence the need for an oscilloscope. That's an outright crappy one there (don't expect to pay less than $1000 for a decent scope or you are likely getting scammed), but still good enough for this purpose. Set it to some 500us/square or so, 1V per square, then put the trigger on rising edge, DC trig, somewhere around 3.5V.

So there's a lot of diverse questions here... which instrument to use, how to use it, how to measure various aspects of this specific circuit etc etc. Since shopping questions are off-topic, I'd recommend asking those in the EE chat instead.

(For example instead of buying a brand new Chinese trashware scope consider spending the same money for a used quality scope. For example cathode ray are still very good performance-wise, just unfashionable. You can probably get a used cathode ray scope of a quality brand with 1000x the performance (I'm not exaggerating) of the Amazon trashware for the same price.)

@EeEmDee In this case an oscilloscope is recommended since you really need to watch the sine wave of the bounce before and after adding RC filter and check that voltage levels are kept above the specified range of the CD4027 input high voltage, rather than the voltage levels of the logic analyser.

Btw if it is 3.3V and the secondary of the relay isn't isolated, why are you even using a relay for in the first place? A BJT or MOSFET would work better and more reliably, with no bounce on the output.

It seems to me that the 4027 is a FF Master-Slave and is not an edge triggered or a data lock-out as in the diagram. The one in the drawing therefore has a different code or at least it is not a 4027.

@FrancescoM. Can you suggest a chip that will do better? Since several have expressed concern over the 4027 (output voltage and that it may not be edge triggered), I'm open to using another cihp. I'm also interested in what to look at for the spects so I understand why another chip is better.

@Lundin Thank you for a lot of good points. I am hoping to be doing a lot more circuit design, but I don't know yet if I will be. I knew whatever scope I started with, I'd be upgrading if I get to do more. Sometimes starting with something that's just cheap and simple is a good learning experience to make it easier to know what to look for in a solid version of that same tool. If I continue, I'll get a good scope.

@Lundin I'm using a relay because the one relay triggers 4 more that handle devices off the PCB this will be on. Those circuits are controlled by DPSTs, where one pole controls the offboard device (on an isolated circuit) and the other pole connects to an ESP32.

There is no reason to not make use of your tools for this question.  Simply place your 10:1 probe on the cap and trigger below the active threshold to see the filter effectively bias the slow decay rate. Also for CMOS you can use 10Meg pullup * 10 nF or 1M* * 100nF using ceramic.  Put trace in 1 ms /div

Also why not use 74LVC07A that can drive relays directly with a flyback diode to Vdd. < 100 mA through Gnd.? https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc07a.pdf

@D.A.S. I took time out for a few chores around here and that idea hit me - I was going to ask about that. I wasn't thinking of the Schmitt trigger in it, I was just thinking of finding what chips I had and use either two inverters or two NAND gates in a series to drive the relay. When you say "flyback diode" could you explain? Is that basically one to help with drainage, so it goes "backwards," across the gate in the 74LVC07?

that's your D2.

You just need to verify if the RC waveforms are within the logic levels needed by the chip, when you apply power.
The problem then moves on to verifying how supply voltage rises when you turn it on, so that the RC waveforms are still within logic levels.
There are many other problems though.
The chip has quite weak output. With 3.3V supply, it might not even drive 0.5mA out to transistor base. Which again limits transistor collector current, and if that is a 3.3V relay, it may need over 100mA. Very large amount of current wasted if all you need is a transistor to turn the 3.3V supply on and off to a subsystem.
The other problems include the chip inputs.
The reset input sure has typical RC with diode to discharge capacitor when power supply drops, to arm it for the next powerup. But it allows for 0.7V over the diode which is more than the absolute maximum rating of the IO pin being only allowed to be 0.5V above supply.
The clock input has no discharge diode at all, so the assumption is the power is cut after capacitor has discharged to below 0.5V.
The 1 milliohm resistors are rather low. Pushing the button or closing the relay contacts will give many amps of current pulse to charge the capacitor. And there is no bypass caps shown for the chip supply, so the current pulse may drop the supply voltage significantly. The switch may also wear out if the switch max current rating is exceeded, so usually you don't connect capacitors directly to small pushbuttons.
The RC time of the signals is 10ms, which means the cap will discharge down to 1% in 50ms.
The 4027, and not many other ICs either, is not intended for such slowly transitioning signals. TI 4027 says that at 5V supply, the clock fall or rise time must be over in 45 microseconds for the chip to work properly within specs. At 3.3V it may be allowed to be lower, but I highly doubt not 1000x longer what the debouncing provides.
I am not saying that the circuit won't work at all, but just be aware where problems might be if it does not work. It might be a good idea to prototype it to see these potential issues happening on the actual circuit in order to avoid them in the next version of the circuit.

The classic debouncer uses an active-low SR latch in the following configuration:


If that's from some book (Art of Electronics) then you must give an attribution where you got that picture. Also this answer does not answer the asked question, it simply provides a debouncer circuit.

Dear Sir Justme, the one I drew using Paint, is a debouncer present in all digital electronics texts for example Floyd's "Digital Electronics". Furthermore It seems to me that the 4027 is a FF Master-Slave and is not an edge triggered or a data lock-out as in the diagram. The one in the drawing therefore has a different code or at least it is not a 4027.

OK, it's your own drawing then. But there is no text explaining how the image you drew answers the question how to test that the original circuit works as planned.

This looks like you're debouncing a double throw switch, as opposed to a single throw. I'm still learning FFs, but with the DT, that actively changes from set to reset, as opposed to a momentary contact ST, which would not ever be changing to reset, but either connecting to set or floating (unless I use a pull down resistor).
